# how I can get the value of JAVA_HOME from my client

Tags: linux, networking, bash, unix

I have nagios client and server, how I can get the value of JAVA_HOME from my client? I have use to set shell command in script that is running from remote host: echo $JAVA_HOME and printenv | grep "JAVA_HOME" doesnt help.

Comment: also asked on http://superuser.com/q/660686/4714

Comment: I don't understand the use case: why does the server need to know about the client's environment?

Comment: this is a task to do, i think it is stupid, but our clients need this

Answer (score 0):

How I worked around this:

```
    echo $localvar > ~/tmpfile
    rcp ~/tmpfile me@myremotelocation:~
    ssh -t me@myremotelocation 'remotevar = `cat ~/tmpfile`'
```

$remotevar on server should be the same as $localvar on client
Scheduled it as a cronjob. Not the most elegant way but it works like a rock since.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` may not be properly set on client's system.

Find java exact location first.

```
$ type -p java
/home/user/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java
```

Notice that the returned path is not the same as `JAVA_HOME`. (If no path is returned, java is not installed)

Then `JAVA_HOME` sets the path to one that containing the `/bin` dir:

`export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdk1.7.0_02/`

`export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`